# Mounting issue on EC2 (mount/: permission denied)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-efs

I am trying to mount efs file system on my AWS EC2 folder /efs and I am using the following codes.

`RUN sudo chmod -R 777 /efs`

`RUN sudo mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport 172.XX.X.XX:/ /efs`

I am also getting this error message

`command '/bin/bash -c sudo mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport 172.XX.X.XX:/ /efs' returned a non-zero code: 32`

I am on my dockerfile and using ubuntu to figure this out and I am really hoping for someone help me with this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

please take a look at the code sample below. It is confirmed working on Ubuntu 18

```
# EFS
echo "INSTALLING EFS START"
cd /tmp/
sudo apt-get -y install binutils
git clone https://github.com/aws/efs-utils
cd efs-utils
./build-deb.sh
sudo apt-get -y install ./build/amazon-efs-utils*deb
cd /tmp/
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/efs
sudo mount -t efs ${ElasticFileSystemId}:/ /mnt/efs/
echo "INSTALLING EFS END"
```